# Subring of product of local rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Suppose $A = \prod_{i=1}^n A_i\ $ where the $A_i$ are local rings. Suppose $B$ is a subring of $A$ such that the projection of $B$ on each $A_i$ is surjective. I want to prove that $B$ is isomorphic to the product of $m$ local rings where $m \le n$ and equality if and only if $B=A$.

My professor told us as a hint that we should use an induction argument and consider for each $i$ the ideal $a_i=A_i \cap B$ in $B$.

I would appreciate any hints on this problem and I am a little confused by his hint. What is 
$a_i=A_i \cap B$ in $B$
supposed to mean? I do not understand this intersection as it seems we are comparing two different types of sets; elements of $B$ which are $n$ tuples of elements of $A_i$ and elements of $A_i$

Comment: I guess $A_i\subset A$ is the ideal of $n$ tuples that are of the form $(0,...,a_i,0,...,0)$. In other way, $A_i$ is identified with the ideal of elements that are $0$ everywhere except at the $i$-th coordinate.

Comment: @user26857 it seems like the user is interested in a subdirect product of rings, and the "projection of $B$ " would refer rather to the the restriction of each natural projection to $B$. The case of $n=1$ entails $B=A_1=A$, as you say.

Comment: @michael each $A_i$ has an isomorphic copy in the product consisting of the set of elements that are zero outside of coordinate i. The hint is referring to the intersection of that with B.

Comment: @rschwieb,roland: that sounds right, that must be it.

Comment: though i understand the problem and hint now i really do not see how to proceed or how $a_i=A_i \cap B$ is important.

Comment: I also have quite a lot of trouble in seeing how an induction argument could be used here.

Comment: @MichaelMoore Hint : $A/A_i=\prod_{j\neq i} A_j$. Can you find the induction argument here ?

Comment: well all i really see is that if we assume the hypothesis for n-1 then we can get that $B/a_n$ is the product of some number of local rings less than n-1.